# how to get a list of particular file type in a folder and subfolders in linux and sort by file size

Tags: linux, sorting, find, filesize

how to get a list of particular file type  in a folder and sub folders in Linux and sort by file size

This is what i tried

```
find . -type f -name "*xml" | sort -r -n
```

It did not sort the files based on size

Comment: Got it by doing this

find . -type f -name "*xml" -size +10k -exec ls -ls {} \+ | sort -n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can print the top 50 this way:

```
find . -type f -iname "*xml" -exec du {} + | sort -rn | head -n50
```

obviously drop the `head` if you want all of them

```
find . -iname "*txt" -exec du {} + | sort -rn
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i got it by doing this 

find . -type f -name "*xml" -size +10k -exec ls -ls {} \+ | sort -n